# How to do check for a palindrome in Python?

Tags: python

Hi I'm working on a python function `isPalindrome(x)` for integers of three digits that returns True if the hundreds digit equals the ones digit and false otherwise.  I know that I have to use strings here and this is what I have:

```
def isPal(x):
    if str(1) == str(3):
        return "True"

    else:
        return "False"
```

the `str(0)` is the units place and `str(2)` is the hundreds place.  All I'm getting is False?  Thanks!

Comment: consider what you're converting to a `str` and what happens with `x`.

Comment: Why not just turn the string into a list and compare list element [0] with element [2]

Comment: I have a suspicion this needs a `homework` tag.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Or an `interview question` tag.

Comment: @sr2222 Is it even possible to ask SO mid-interview...?

Comment: @zigg Phone interview+silent keyboard...

Comment: Awkward moment if the interviewer is on SO and sees you posting the question

Comment: @sr2222 I guess I just assumed even with all other things considered, you're either silent or filling the time with BS... in which case you're making yourself look pretty dumb.

Comment: this looks like part of project euler problem 4 - see here for a solution: http://ferretfarmer.wordpress.com/2013/09/26/project-euler-problem-4/

Answer (score 6):

Array access is done with `[]`, not `()`. Also if you are looking for hundreds and units, remember that arrays are 0 indexed, here is a shortened version of the code.

```
def is_pal(num):
    return num[0] == num[2]

>>> is_pal('123')
False
>>> is_pal('323')
True
```

You might want to take in the number as a parameter and then convert it to a string:

```
def is_pal(num):
    x = str(num)
    return x[0] == x[2]
```

Note that you can simply just check if string is equal to it's reverse which works for any number of digits:

```
>>> x = '12321'
>>> x == x[::-1]
True
```

Comment: Thanks I got this though isPal(-343) returns False.                 def isPal(x):
    return str(x)[0] == str(x)[2]

Comment: String conversion is poor performance. Better to use division and mod (see my response for some bench-marking).

Comment: @GeorgePutin That's also fine

Comment: @GeorgePutin In that case you could take `abs()` of the integer

Answer (score 3):

`str(1)` will create a string of the integer value 1. Which won't equal the string value of the integer value 3 - so it's always False.

You should return `True` and `False`, rather than strings of "True" and "False"...

This is what you're aiming for taking into account the above... (which works with any length)

```
def pal(num):
    forward = str(num)
    backward = ''.join(reversed(forward))
    return forward == backward
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `str(1) == '1'` and `str(3) == '3'`.  You're also returning string values reading `'True'` and `'False'` instead of using the actual `True` and `False` values.

Let me propose a much simpler function for you:

```
def isPal(x):
    s = str(x)          # convert int to str
    return s == s[::-1] # return True if s is equal to its reverse
```

`s[::-1]` creates a reverse of the string; e.g. `'foo'[::-1] == 'oof'`.  This works because of extended slice notation.

Answer (score 1):

`str()` casts a value into a `str`. You want to access each character. You might want to benchmark a few different techniques.

```
>>> t1 = timeit.Timer(stmt="""\
... def isPal(x):
...     return x//100 == x%10
... isPal(434)
... isPal(438)
... """)
>>> t2 = timeit.Timer(stmt="""\
... def isPal(x):
...     return str(x)[0] == str(x)[2]
... isPal(434)
... isPal(438)
... """)
>>> print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t1.timeit(number=100000)/100000)
0.97 usec/pass
>>> print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t2.timeit(number=100000)/100000)
2.04 usec/pass
```

So, it looks like the mod technique works:

```
def isPal(x):
    return x//100 == x%10
```

Comment: Consider using `x//100` instead of `x/100` since you want integer division here.

Comment: @mgilson: If the OP is handling integers as the question states then this makes no difference, though of course if they are using floats you're right.

Comment: (and incidentally none of the string conversion techniques work if the number is represented by a float without first converting to an int)

Comment: @mutzmatron -- it does make a difference in python3.x.  Might as well get into the habit now.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why people are sticking to the string idea when division and modulo will do:

```
def isPal(x):
    return (x/100)%10 == x%10
```

if the number is no larger than 999 (3 digits as the OP stated) then it simplifies to

```
def isPal(x):
    return x/100 == x%10
```

Comment: Because maybe it needs a few more seconds to understand what your code is actually doing? I'd prefer clarity over performance in most cases (i.e. always when performance is not absolutely crucial -> see premature optimization).

Comment: @nyarlathotep: Actually this is the standard *numerical* way to see if the hundreds digit equals the units digit...

Comment: True. But then why still call it isPal? Because it is only a palindrome if the reverse notation equals the "normal" one, but your function also works for numbers with more than 3 digits, and still only compares 1st and 3rd character... back to the original topic: maybe most people were just influenced by the way the question was written... or were suspecting that the function should actually work for arbitrary strings

Comment: @nyarlathotep - You're right I went overboard with the first more general version - the OP states "3 -digit integer" so the second version was sufficient.

Comment: it's still weird why one would write an isPalindrome function which only works for 3-digit numbers... but that's outside of the scope of OP's question I guess :D

Comment: Palindromes are not just numbers, but words too maybe that's why the division approach isn't so obvious.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: True, though the "of integers with 3 digits" immediately made me think of a numerical approach.

Answer (score 0):

`str(x)` delivers the string value of whatever you pass to it, so in your case the string `"1"` or the string `"3"`. But what you actually want is to access the 1st and 3rd digit of the given number. So, first you want to convert that number to string (e.g. with str(num)), and then you have to consider that indices in strings begin with 0, not with 1.
So working code culd e.g. look like this:

```
def isPal(x):
  if str(x)[0] == str(x)[2]:
    return 'true'
  else:
    return 'false'
```

Output:

```
> isPal(101)
true
> isPal (203)
false
```

Answer (score 0):

`str(1)` just gives you the string representation of the number `1`:

```
>>> x = 357
>>> str(1)
'1'
```

What you want is the *first index* of the string representation of `x`.

```
>>> x = 357
>>> str(x)    #string representation of x
'357'
>>> str(x)[0] #first index of that
'3'
>>> str(x)[2] #third index of that
'7'
>>> str(x)[0]==str(x)[2] #compare 1st and last
False
>>> x = 525
>>> str(x)[0]==str(x)[2] #compare 1st and last
True
```

Answer (score 0):

you compare number 1 and 3, but you needt to compare index of input variable.

```
x = 1000
def isPal(x):
    return str(x[-1]) == str(x[-3]):
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you still need to study [Python syntax](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.3/reference/index.html)

Here is a way to achieve what you need :

```
>>> def isPal(x):
...     x_as_str = str(x)
...     if len(x_as_str) != 3:
...         raise Exception("{} is not of length 3".format(x))
...     return x_as_str[0] == x_as_str[2]
...
>>> isPal(42)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 4, in isPal
Exception: 42 is not of length 3
>>> isPal(420)
False
>>> isPal(424)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

A smaller solution for this would be:

```
def isPalindrome(x):    
    return str(x) == str(x)[::-1]
```

This will work for words and integer values.

Answer (score -1):

```
def is_palindrome() :
a=(raw_input("enter the name : "))
b=a[::-1]
    if b == a:
    print " it is palindarome"
    else:
    print "  it is not palindarome"
```

is_palindrome()

Comment: Please review your indentation, formatting and spelling of the word "palindrome".